# Loop displaying undefined and I can't see where I've set it wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I'm looping through data from a .net web service through jsonp. Similar code works elsewhere but I can't see where i've gone wrong here.

The data is retreived through:

```
if (pageId === 'alerts') {
        var Username = localStorage.getItem("Username");
        var SessionKey = localStorage.getItem("SessionID");
        console.log(Username);
        console.log(SessionKey);
        $.mobile.loading( 'show', { theme: "b", text: "Loading", textonly: false});
        $.ajax({
            crossDomain: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "http://redacted/GetData.asmx/GetLostAnimals",
            data: {Username: Username, SessionKey: SessionKey },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: myAlerts
        });
    }

var lostSelectedPet = 0;
function myAlerts(data)
{
    $("#alertsListMissingPets").empty();
    $.mobile.loading( 'hide', { theme: "b", text: "Loading", textonly: false});

    $.each(data, function(index) {
        console.log(data[index].LostDate)
        $("#alertsListMissingPets").append(" <li><a href=\"#\">"+ data[index].AnimalKey + " <span class=\"ui-li-count\">12</span></a></li>");
    });
    $("#alertsListMissingPets").listview('refresh');
}

$(document).on('click', '#alertsListMissingPets li a', function(){
    localStorage.setItem("lostSelectedPet", $(this).attr('data-custom'));
    editingId  = $(this).attr('data-custom');

});
```

The json returned is like:

```
callback(
 {
    AnimalKey: "f152e1c6baca181d9f3ca1f18c91cc41f23fc122545d9c8bff9f4cb2ea449874",
    LostDate: "11/06/2014 16:14:19",
    FoundDate: "",
    LostKey: "7560733274a7ca2ec43a85fcb9abd345fdc876acffac2b75ace7946035122fbd",
    Resp: "OK"
 }
)
```

However, this returns - It shows 5 items but theres only one result, the json above is the full response.

[image]

Comment: If that's the entire returned `data` -- it's not an array; hence you don't need to `.each` loop. Just access it with `data.AnimalKey`. If an array is also a valid return value, you can check with `$.isArray` or some such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not looping over an array, you are looping over an object. You have 5 keys in the object, hence why there is 5 rows in the output.

Change the response to be an array.

```
callback(
 [{  //<-- added [
    AnimalKey: "f152e1c6baca181d9f3ca1f18c91cc41f23fc122545d9c8bff9f4cb2ea449874",
    LostDate: "11/06/2014 16:14:19",
    FoundDate: "",
    LostKey: "7560733274a7ca2ec43a85fcb9abd345fdc876acffac2b75ace7946035122fbd",
    Resp: "OK"
 }]    //<-- added ]
)
```

Comment: D'oh! I missed that. Thank you so much